# Unpack list of dicts into list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that includes a column of lists of dictionaries.

```
    list_dicts
id  
a1  [{name:'cat'}, {name:'dog'}]
a2  [{name:'toy'}, {name:'boy'}] 
a3  [{name:'jack'},{name:'jill'},{name:'sam'}] 
a4  [{name:'pig'}]
```

Every key in the list of dicts is 'name'. I want to create a list of all the values associated with the 'name' keys and append the new column to the existing dataframe, as shown below.

```
    list_from_dict
id  
a1  ['cat','dog']
a2  ['toy','boy'] 
a3  ['jack','jill','sam'] 
a4  ['pig']
```

How can I achieve this? I understand it'll probably use a lambda function, but not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with list comprehension and without a lambda function in just one line:

```
df['list_from_dict'] = [[x['name'] for x in list_dict] for list_dict in df['list_dicts']]
```

Comment: I get the error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Comment: That makes it seem as though when calling x['name'] it is attempting to index a list rather than a dictionary.

Comment: Yes. I tried to changing x['name'] to x.values() to maybe pull out the values if it detects a dictionary, but it just gave the error 'list object has no attribute values'.

Comment: Can you run it and share the output when you just leave it as "x for x in list_dict" instead of "x['name'] for x in list_dict" so I can see the output?

Comment: I have no idea why it would look like that - perhaps try using a lambda function like you originally proposed:

df['list_from_dict'] = df['list_dicts'].apply(lambda list_dict: [x['name'] for x in list_dict])

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you print out a segment of the pandas dataframe as it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169377/discussion-between-justin-malin-and-guru).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `pd.Series.apply` with a custom `lambda` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list_dicts': [[{'name': 'cat'}, {'name': 'dog'}],
                                  [{'name': 'toy'}, {'name': 'boy'}],
                                  [{'name': 'jack'}, {'name': 'jill'}, {'name': 'sam'}],
                                  [{'name': 'pig'}]]},
                  index=['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'])

df['list_dicts'] = df['list_dicts'].apply(lambda x: [next(iter(d.values())) for d in x])

print(df)

           list_dicts
a1         [cat, dog]
a2         [toy, boy]
a3  [jack, jill, sam]
a4              [pig]
```

Comment: I get the error 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable'. Some rows in that column contain nans, and maybe some floats. How can I bypass this?

Comment: @guru, I don't get this error. Did you copy/paste the above code *exactly* ? Or are you applying the logic on your data which may be different?

Comment: @guru you could check if `d` `isinstance` of a dictionary, otherwise just return its own value.

Comment: so I added the check if isinstance of a dictionary, and that part of the code works now, but now I get the error that 'list' object has no attribute 'values'. I haven't copied the code exactly.